# JSF form validation with Bootstrap modal - modal is closing

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, jsf, modal-dialog

I have a problem with JSF form validation in bootstrap modal. This is code of it:

```
<div id="loginmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                            <h1 class="text-center">Logowanie</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h:form id="loginForm" class="form col-md-12 center-block">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:inputText id="login" class="form-control input-lg" a:placeholder="Login" value="#{loginHelper.login}"  required="true" requiredMessage="Pole &quot;login&quot; jest wymagane.">
                                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="loginMessage"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
                                    <h:message id="loginMessage" for="login" style="color: red;"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h:inputSecret id="haslo" class="form-control input-lg" a:placeholder="Hasło" value="#{loginHelper.haslo}" required="true" requiredMessage="Pole &quot;hasło&quot; jest wymagane.">
                                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="hasloMessage"/>
                                    </h:inputSecret>
                                    <h:message id="hasloMessage" for="haslo" style="color: red;"/>          
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <p:commandButton class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Zaloguj" action="#{loginHelper.validate}" id="zaloguj"/>
                                    <h:message for="zaloguj" style="color: red;"/>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registermodal">Zarejestruj się</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </h:form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Anuluj</button>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

If I use PrimeFaces *p:commandButton*, the dialog doesn't close when validation fails, but no message is displayed. On the other hand, if I use normal *h:commandButton*, the dialog always closes and the whole page is refreshed. After page reload, messages about validation problems are displayed in dialog, but I need to click button to display dialog again.

What I'm tryind to say, is that I need a simple way to prevent dialog from closing when validation error occurs, but also dynamically show validation errors in it. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem main cause is the reload after submit so you can over come this using `f:ajax` since it will not reload the page:

```
  <h:commandButton value="Submit" >
    <f:ajax  render=":formId" listener="#{registerAction.register}"/>
   </h:commandButton>
```

And whenever you want to auto-close the modal due to successful validated submit render a `panelGroup` on that `panelGroup` do a `js` code that closes the modal like following :

```
   <h:panelGroup rendered=#{registerAction.submitSuccess}">
           <script>
               $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('#registerModal').modal('hide');
               });
           </script>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

// `registerAction.submitSuccess` is a boolean flag express valid registeration.